# Pass borderRadius to react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How would I pass a `borderRadius` which is taken from plain `CSS` like

```
border-radius: 50% 50% 4px 50%
```

to `react-native`?

I tried

```
borderRadius: "50% 50% 4px 50%"
```

but that gave me

> expected dynamic type double, but had type string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting each corner individually with `borderBottomLeftRadius`, `borderBottomRightRadius`, `borderTopLeftRadius`, and `borderTopRightRadius`.

Also, when using react the values accept numbers only.

Comment: He'll also need to remove the 'px' and '%' since those won't mean anything to react native.

Answer (score 2):

react-native implements all styles or props in camelCase.
so to provide borderRadius you have to use **borderRadius** style props.
Other style props for border are  **borderTopLeftRadius**,b**orderTopRightRadius**,**borderBottomLeftRadius**,**borderBottomRightRadius**.

example of a circle of 50,50

```
render(){
    return(
    <View style={{height:50, width:50, borderRadius:25, backgroundColor:'#555555'}}/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass percentile values because

> All dimensions in React Native are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels.

This means that you **cannot** use percentages and pixels.

Similarly, `borderRadius` requires a double and not a string and to apply different values for different corners, you need to use

```
borderBottomLeftRadius
borderBottomRightRadius
borderTopLeftRadius
borderTopRightRadius
```

Or, you could write a helper function

```
const getBorderRadius = (borderTopLeftRadius = 0, borderTopRightRadius = 0, borderBottomLeftRadius = 0, borderBottomRightRadius = 0) => {
  return {
    borderTopLeftRadius,
    borderTopRightRadius,
    borderBottomLeftRadius,
    borderBottomRightRadius
  }
}
```

You can then use it like so, in your styles

```
<View styles={Object.assign({ <insert your styles here> }, getBorderRadius(10, 10, 10, 10)} />
```

If your project is supporting of Object Spread (may need [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)) then you can simply write

```
<View styles={{ <insert your styles here>, ...getBorderRadius(10, 10, 10, 10)}}/>
```

If you want to use 50%, you have to calculate it yourself. If you know the height and width of your Component then great that's easy.